Hide some options from Account Journal dropdown in Account Payment popup form
I need to hide certain entries from the Account Journal dropdown and show only a few items.
I've tried inheriting account_payment model to alter the field like below, but it doesn't work
class account_payment(models.Model):
    _name = "account.payment"
    _inherit = "account.payment"

    journal_id = fields.Many2one('account.journal', string='Payment Journal',
                                 domain=[('name', 'in', ('Cash','Insurance','Bank', 'UPI Payment'))])

How do I achieve this?
Thanks

The domain of the journal field is updated when the payment type changes. To use a custom domain, you can rewrite the _onchange_payment_type function:
@api.onchange('payment_type')
def _onchange_payment_type(self):
    if not self.invoice_ids:
        # Set default partner type for the payment type
        if self.payment_type == 'inbound':
            self.partner_type = 'customer'
        elif self.payment_type == 'outbound':
            self.partner_type = 'supplier'
        else:
            self.partner_type = False
    # Set payment method domain
    res = self._onchange_journal()
    if not res.get('domain', {}):
        res['domain'] = {}
    res['domain']['journal_id'] = self.payment_type == 'inbound' and [('at_least_one_inbound', '=', True)] or self.payment_type == 'outbound' and [('at_least_one_outbound', '=', True)] or []
    res['domain']['journal_id'].append(('type', 'in', ('bank', 'cash')))
    return res


Thanks for the response. Unfortuntely, this odoo is a part of a bahmni installation, which has the payment_type field set as invisible :(

The field is hidden by default

ok, but I can't make it visible - which is not required/allowed. To trigger the above method, wouldn't that field need to be visible ?

I tested the function on the invoice Register Payment form, the payment type field is hidden and on change function is triggered

Have you tried replacing the function above and checking the result?

Yeah, it works! - it works even when I just add that method with nothing but a pass inside it.
@api.onchange('payment_type')     def _onchange_payment_type(self):         pass
So, I'm confused about what this method actually does.

It sets the journal field domain when the payment type changes.

wait, it was actually showing 4 payment modes - Cash,Card,Bank & UPI. So, I just changed the last but one line to res['domain']['journal_id'].append(('name', 'in', ('Cash','Insurance','Bank', 'UPI Payment'))) and now I get the desired options.
